# What does BNG stand for

Tags: dataset

When i look at the available datasets in https://www.openml.org i often see a BNG dataset with no further information about it.

Can someone explane what BNG means in this context?

I am especially interested in this dataset: https://www.openml.org/d/1389

Has anyone more information about where this data set comes from?

Comment: Try asking the author: http://liacs.leidenuniv.nl/~rijnjnvan/

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Already sendet him a mail. Will post the answer here :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Bayesian Network Generated (BNG) datasets are a set of artificially generated datasets openly available on OpenML. These datasets were generated to fill the need for a large heterogeneous set of large datasets. This paper describes the BNG generator best:
[Algorithm Selection on Data Streams](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-11812-3_28).

Small quote from the paper about the BNG data generator:

> The generator takes a dataset as input, and outputs a data stream containing
>   a similar concept, with a predefined number of instances. The input dataset is
>   preprocessed with the following operations: all missing values are first replaced by the majority value of that attribute, and numeric attributes are discretized using Weka’s binning algorithm.

A personal note: For general Machine Learning studies, I would refrain from using BNG (or any other kind of artificially generated) datasets, as the concept is generally simpler than the original dataset. Instead, it is recommendable to use a per-defined benchmark suite, such as the [OpenML-100](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.03731).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would be very useful if this information would be at the openml.org page, because thats the place where many BNG datasets are discovered.